# Read-only files icon in "Places" on Komodo Edit

Tags: icons, readonly, komodoedit

I am trying to change the icon for read-only files in "Places". I want to see a lock icon for read-only files, such as tab icons.

[image]

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom stylesheet with something like this:

```
@lockedimage: url('chrome://komodo/skin/images/locked-file_icon.png');

tab[widget="openfilesViewbox"] 
  {
  .tab-icon[alt="Places"] 
    {
    list-style-image: @lockedimage !important;
    }  
  }
```

**References**

- [Customizing Komodo using userChrome.css](http://community.activestate.com/faq/customizing-komodo-ui)
- [Komodo File Locations](http://community.activestate.com/faq/komodo-file-locations)
- [Komodo Image Repository](http://svn.openkomodo.com/openkomodo/browse/openkomodo/trunk/src/chrome/komodo/skin/images)
- [Komodo Icon Stylesheet](http://svn.openkomodo.com/openkomodo/view/openkomodo/trunk/src/chrome/komodo/skin/plat/shared/icons.less)
- [Komodo Icon Variables](http://svn.openkomodo.com/openkomodo/view/openkomodo/trunk/src/chrome/komodo/skin/plat/shared/_config/icons.less)